# Inequality extension to the boundary of domain

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Then I know that the function $|f|^3$ is subharmonic on $\mathbb{D}$. So for every $r<1$ I have by the mean-value property
$$ |f(0)|^3\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^3\,d\theta$$
but I want to prove the above inequality for $r=1$ too. Can I argue as follows? Let $r_n$ be a sequence such that $r_n\rightarrow 1$. Then by taking $\liminf$ I have
$$|f(0)|^3\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(r_ne^{i\theta})|^3\,d\theta \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \liminf_{r_n\rightarrow 1}|f(r_ne^{i\theta})|^3\,d\theta$$ $$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^3\,d\theta$$ 
where the exchange of integral and $\liminf$ is allowed by Fatou's lemma and the last equality is true because of continuity of $f$ and $|\cdot|^3$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Fatou's lemma gives you the reverse inequality, so your reasoning is not correct. However, in this case you have uniform convergence of the integrands, so there is actually a much easier direct argument.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Thanks, I thought something was wrong. How do I know that the convergence is uniform?

Comment: Continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, that gives you $f(re^{i\theta}) \to f(e^{i\theta})$ as $r\to 1$, uniformly in $\theta$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Of course. Thanks again, if you want post an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatou's lemma gives the reverse inequality, so the argument is not correct. However, since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, you have $|f(r e^{i\theta})|^3 \to |f(e^{i\theta})|^3$ as $r\to 1$, uniformly in $\theta$, so 
$$
\lim_{r\to 1} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(r e^{i\theta})|^3 \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{i\theta})|^3 \, d\theta
$$
and the desired inequality follows directly.

If your argument worked, it would hold for the a.e. radial limit $u^*(e^{i\theta}) = \lim_{r\to 1} u(re^{i\theta})$ of a subharmonic function $u$ in the disk, even without assuming continuity. However, this is wrong, as you can see from $u(z) = \mathrm{Re}\frac{1+z}{1-z}$. This function $u$ is harmonic in the disk, has radial limit $0$ almost everywhere on the boundary, and $u(0)=1$.